# How to setup netbeans to develop android applications?

Tags: android, netbeans

I am starting to learn android development. I need to set my netbeans IDE 6.8 to develop android. I have downloaded and installed Android SDK. I have also installed nandroid plugin for netbeans. The next thing I need to do is to register android as one of the platform in Netbeans.

I am struck here. Even after selecting the android sdk folder in the Add platform window, the finish/next button is not active. I am using Windows. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check this [video](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDUQtwIwAw&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IaA7SVDEQcQ&rct=j&q=using%20android%20sdk%20with%20netbeans&ei=DSN6Tb2XHsaWhQfB9MHyBg&usg=AFQjCNFR5yHacaXJpyiEguHrnKTadOZ0og&cad=rja), if you want my personal advice try to use eclipse, i always use netbeans for development but for android the plug-in for netbeans is not that good .. eclipse plug-in provide a gui interface and drag & drop functionalities, XML editors and lots more .. give eclipse a shot .. it went great with me

Comment: +1 for eclipse recommendation. Think of Eclipse is related to Android like a Hammer is related to a nail. I mean you could possibly get the nail into the wall with a screwdriver but... okay excuse me got stock with the metaphor..